# Firefox not rendering @font-face style correctly

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

Hey guys, for some reason, I have FireFox not complying with the supposed "bullet-proof" method of getting a custom font in every modern browser.

Well, I hope I'm just doing something wrong, because it looks to me as though it really should be working.

Here is my CSS style:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SMB';
    src: url('/css/type/SMB.eot');
    src: local('ò∫'),
             url('/css/type/SMB.woff') format('woff'),
             url('/css/type/SMB.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('/css/type/SMB.svg#webfont') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

My URL is http://www.marioplanet.com if you would like to check out the live FireFox problem.

Comment: Your website broke my ears. :p

Comment: I'm getting the custom font in IE, Chrome and FF3.6.8.In Chrome and FF the font looks bolder, but definitely SMB. Maybe it's your browser?

Comment: @msw is like waaay too loud?

@Inrbob, let me check on a different computer..

Answer (score 1):

You can refer MDN Web Docs  [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)